# Opening Web Cam For Capturing Image In Asp.net Application

Tags: asp.net, webcam

I am using `Asp.net/C#` for developing an online banking application.In my new member form i have a requirement wherein i need to open a `webcam` to capture `image` of that member and then display it on the form ,,, i wanted to know that how is it possible to open a `web cam` in my `web application` , i guess it wont be possible in `Asp.net` ... Can anybody point me in right direction ,,, any suggestions are welcome.
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not in Asp.net , but you can use it through Silverlight, check this out: http://www.silverlightshow.net/items/Capturing-the-Webcam-in-Silverlight-4.aspx

Comment: Flash allows you to do it too.

Comment: Sure, but Actionscript is not as intuitive as xaml + .Net is (my opinion ;-) )

Comment: I completely agree. But just adding another option, but it didn't warrant a new post. Silverlight is being end of lifed though :)

Comment: So should i go for Silverlight , and if i go with it ,, will it hamper the performance of the site ....

Comment: I've used Silverlight in a couple of projects and I've not found any performance issue yet.